# Bigquery concatatenation

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT WEEK(timestamp) AS WEEK
       EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(prods) AS Total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1

above query returns week # and total. I want to show week column values as WEEK 21, WEEK 22, WEEK 23 (by concatenating 'WEEK' string to the week #)

Comment: You should start showing some attempts to address such simple items by yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  'Week ' + STRING(WEEK(day)) AS week, 
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(prods) AS Total 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY 1
```